# python mss ScreenShotError

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-mss

So basically I'm just messing around with mss (python2.7 *and* 3.6), and I have the following code:

```
import mss
import cv2
import numpy as np

with mss.mss() as sct:
    mon = {'top':40,'left':0, 'width': 800, 'height': 750}
    try:
        img = np.array(sct.grab(mon))
        cv2.imshow('Screen',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    except mss.ScreenShotError:
        print(sct.get_error_details())
```

It *should* just take a screenshot and display it, but it just dies with the following information:

```
{'xerror_details': {'type': 0, 'serial': 405, 'error_code': 7, 'request_code': 0, 'minor_code': 0}, 'xerror': 'BadFont (invalid Font parameter)'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have read something about resources not being freed, but before that I messed around with code without the with statement, and *without* calling free or close, or whatever. It crashed, I did a reboot, to no avail.

Comment: What MSS version? And what is the content of the `DISPLAY` envar? I just tired with the 4.0.2 on Python 3.6 and your code works just fine.

Comment: @Tiger-222 I have Mss 4.0.2, and echo $DISPLAY shows :0. It used to work, but it no longer does, after I have ran it a few times

Comment: Is it the exact code you gave that is raising such error?

Comment: Yes, it is the code

Comment: Does it works with 4.0.1 or 4.0.0?